# Scalastyle Boolean expression can be simplified

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalastyle

Scalastyle (intellij 2016.1 defaults) says this boolean expression can be simplified

```
val t = Option(true)
val f = Option(false)
if(t.contains(true) && f.contains(false)) {
  println("booop")
}
```

I can get rid of this by changing the if to:

```
if(t.contains(true).&&(f.contains(false)))
```

Or by changing && to &

But not really seeing how this is simplifying it, could anyone explain what's going on?

**Update**
It doesn't appear to be related to if the vals are known at compile time, or them being locally defined. The following code also get's the warning that the expression can be simplfied:

```
object TestFoo {
  def bar(t: Option[Boolean]) = {
    val f = Option(scala.util.Random.nextBoolean)
    if (t.contains(true) && f.contains(false)) println("booop")
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) = bar(t = Option(scala.util.Random.nextBoolean))
}
```

I just don't get how I'm supposed to make that any simpler, is there some strange Option[Boolean] comparing I'm missing out on?

Comment: I was having the same problem.  Seems like a bug in ScalaStyle.  Changing to infix must just sidestep their regexes for this situation.  Using contains seems like the simplest way for this situation.

Comment: There is a newer question with related topic: [Simplifying Option\[Boolean\] expression in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65123370/2359227)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to suggest you being consistent with the method call usage. Either everything in infix form:

```
(t contains true) && (f contains false)
```

Or everything in regular method call form:

```
t.contains(true).&&(f.contains(false))
```

Answer (score 1):

With your values, `t.contains(true).&&(f.contains(false))` always returns `true`. So you could simplify it by simply writing `true`, i.e by just executing the `print` without an `if` condition.

Comment: Sorry, the actual code does not use values known at compile time. I've added another example to clarify